# Написание мини-почтового сервиса

Tags: pop3, php, email

Может видел кто "сделай сам" на тему мини-почтового сервиса?
Приём, отправка, спам папка - больше ничего не нужно. Как такое реализовать на РНР?
Хотя бы ссылочками поделитесь пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае, если по каким-либо причинам вы желаете реализовать данный функционал самостоятельно, то начните с установки `sendmail` на сервере и `php` скрипте, который будет отправлять электронную почту через стандартные функции `php`.

Если хочется установить что-либо готовое "из коробки", то имеет смысл запрячь гугл с запросами `php e-mail service`, `php email framework`, `php cms email module` и т.п

---

Отмечу, что есть и промежуточный вариант - все современные `php` фреймворки типа `CodeIgniter`, `Symfony` и т.п предоставляют набор более-менее удобных средств для работы с e-mail, и, вероятно, *разобраться с ними будет проще, чем писать все самостоятельно* (как я предложил в самом первом варианте).

Другое дело, что в этом случае задача потребует "разбирательств" с внутренним устройством и идеологией используемого фреймворка, что, может быть, не входит в ваши планы :)

**P.S**

Я сейчас подумал, что, например, если вы совершенно не представляете себе, как устроен спам-фильтр и какие алгоритмы применяются для фильтрации этого самого спама, то о полноценном варианте номер 1, пожалуй, стоит забыть. *В таком случае лучше воспользоваться вторым или третьим способом.*